# How to access a specific value from memory

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, ipc

I've got the following code:

```
int main {
    int* x = new int;
    *x = 5;
    std::string input = " ";
    while (true) {
        std::cin >> input;
        if (input == "show") {
            std::cout << *x << " " << x << "\n"; // Output value and address of x if "show" is the console input
        }
        else if (input == "exit") {    // Close the program if "exit" is the console input
            break;
        }
    }
    delete x;
}
```

this code should output the value of x and the address. This looks something like this:

```
5
0000020445E210E0
```

And now i need another external c++ program with a pointer to the address of `x` so it can change the value of `x`.
But how can I create a pointer which points to this exact address to change the value?

Comment: For what purpose do you need this? Pure curiosity, or are you trying to solve a specific problem? Because the short answer is: you can’t, individual processes are isolated from outside modification. The much longer, and much more complicated, answer is: you need to request the operating system’s permission to access another process’ memory, which requires OS-specific libraries and won’t work in pure C++.

Comment: This is very dangerous, but you can simply do```int *pointer = (int *) 0000020445E210E0;```

Comment: @newbie That works on microcontrollers (after fixing the typo) but not on most modern operating systems.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Can microcontrollers run multiple programs in parallel?

Comment: @eerorika: not directly, but I can remember having implemented some kind on multi-processing/multi-threading in a MS/DOS system to handle multiple modems at the same time. It only required a tiny library in assembly language for the *context* management. This could be easily ported on a microcontroller.

Comment: @eerorika Good point. But *if they could* …

Comment: @KonradRudolph I have got multiple processes that have to share values. If this is so complicated have you got any idea how multiple processes can communicate in an easier way?

Comment: @coolplayzini the fie answer from eerorika answers just that

Comment: @coolplayzini In that case, look up *interprocess communication*. It’s a big topic, and every OS has preferred APIs for it. But in general I’d recommend you either use (named) pipes or sockets.

Answer (score 2):

> And now i need another external c++ program with a pointer to the address of x so it can change the value of x. But how can I create a pointer which points to this exact address to change the value?

You cannot. On (modern) systems that support multi-processing, each process has distinct virtual memory space and generally cannot point to memory of other processes.

---

Some alternatives:

- You could create a dynamic object in *shared memory*. There is no standard way to allocate shared memory in C++.

  - Typically you would need some form of locking to avoid race conditions. You could use inter process mutexes/semaphores. There are no standard inter process mutexes/semaphores in C++.
- Instead of dealing with pointers, you could communicate the value of the pointed object. All of the following alternatives require the data to be serialised into a stream of bytes. There is no standard way in C++ to serialise arbitrary data into a stream of bytes. Unlike the other things in this list, serialisation is at least possible to implement without relying on any operating system interfaces.

  - You can use pipes. There is no standard way in C++ to create pipes.
  - You can use a message queue. There is no standard way in C++ to create inter process message queues.
  - Network sockets are commonly used for Inter Process Communication. This allows for communication over a network, but also works between processes on the same system. There is no standard way to do networking in C++.
  - You can resort to writing into a file in one process and read in another. While file access is possible in standard C++, there is no standard way to lock files which is essential in multi processing to avoid race conditions. There is also no standard way to get notification of a changed file in C++.

As you may have noticed from the list, there are no standard ways for IPC in C++ at all.

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, this is impossible with processes being locked into their own address space, which is done in all modern operating systems, otherwise it would be incredibly dangerous with viruses and stuff like that.

What you want here is a way to share memory between processes, and this is not impossible. For example, here is [POSIX shared memory API](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/posix-shared-memory-api/), which does exactly that. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/creating-named-shared-memory) seems to be an alternative for Windows.

Aside from that, there's also a whole lot of ways to perform inter-process communication - from networking to pipes, files, and other stuff like that.

Comment: This is *not* a protection against viruses, it’s a protection against accidents: processes *can* gain access to other memory space, they just have to go through the operating system to do so (as long as the process has sufficient permissions, so this can’t be used to gain elevated permissions).

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your answers i guess I'll try with sockets for interprocess communication

Comment: @KonradRudolph, Well, agreed, no problems here. Just thought that virus buzzword would be more convincing =3 

To be honest, I'd be pretty scared of what could have happen if modern C++-built applications (all UBs included, heh) could access memory of other processes just by walking out of their allocated memory with out-of-range accesses. :-D

It would be a hell to debug... =3

Comment: @coolplayzini, you could accept one of the answers, you know.. :)